# Is this simple drawing a category?

Tags: category-theory

[image: Diagramme]

As far as I can tell this is a category but I am not 100% sure. 
Objects are A, B, C. Arrows are f and g.

Could someone please confirm that this drawing is indeed a category?
So no arrows need to be between C and B ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes. The way you've drawn $f$ and $g$ they can't be composed, so there's no further data to specify.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: I replaced the big photo by a smaller cleaner diagram. I hope it is ok with you.

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I don't know why the people are using again comments to answer the question; this way even "answered" questions will stay on the list of unanswered questions.)

Yes, this is a category. Actually, every preordered set (a set with a reflexive and transitive relation $\leq$) can be regarded as a category in a natural way, where there is exactly one morphism $x \to y$ when $x \leq y$.

In your case, you consider the preordered set $\{A,B,C\}$ with $A \leq B$ and $A \leq C$ (and of course $A \leq A$, $B \leq B$, $C \leq C$).

Comment: I admit my motivations are selfish: I don't want the list of questions I've recently answered to be cluttered by low-vote answers where I just say "yes" or whatever.